# Соблюдение Федерального Закона РФ "О защите персональных данных"

Tags: поддержка

На сайте собираются личные/персональные данные.
В профиле есть специальный блок для этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте зарегистрированы граждане РФ. Есть **Закон РФ "О персональных данных" N 152-ФЗ**. В соответствии с этим законом сайты, на которых происходит сбор  персональных данных, **обязаны уведомить Роскомнадзор** и выполнить другие требования действующего законодательства РФ.
Соблюдается ли 152-ФЗ на сайте http://ru.stackoverflow.com?
На странице http://stackexchange.com/legal/contact все на английском.

Признаков того, что на сайте соблюдаются требования законодательства РФ, нет.

Прошу администратора сайта ответить на вопрос и принять все меры для устранения нарушений.

Answer (score 13):

152 ФЗ не применим к ruSO, по крайней мере на данный момент. Почитайте
[Официальные разъяснения минсвязи о применимости закона](http://www.minsvyaz.ru/ru/personaldata/), раздел *Сфера действия ФЗ-242 по территории и кругу лиц*:

О наличии направленности интернет-сайта на территорию Российской Федерации могут свидетельствовать следующие обстоятельства:

1. использование доменного имени, связанного с Российской Федерацией или субъектом РФ (.ru, .рф., .su, .москва., moscow и т.п.) - **нет**

и (или)

2. наличие русскоязычной версии интернет-сайта, созданной владельцем такого сайта или по его поручению иным лицом (использование на сайте или самим пользователем плагинов, предоставляющих функционал автоматизированных переводчиков с различных языков не должно приниматься во внимание). - **да, но**

При этом поскольку русский язык широко используется в некоторых странах за пределами Российской Федерации, **для определения направленности интернет-сайта именно на территорию Российской Федерации дополнительно необходимо наличие как минимум одного** из следующих элементов:

- возможности осуществления расчетов в российских рублях; - **нет**
- возможности исполнения заключенного на таком интернет-сайте договора на территории Российской Федерации (доставки товара, оказания услуги или пользования цифровым контентом на территории России) - **нет**
- использование рекламы на русском языке, отсылающей к соответствующему интернет-сайту, или иных обстоятельств, явно свидетельствующих о намерении владельца интернет-сайта включить российский рынок в свою бизнес-стратегию. - **компания не предоставляет никаких платных услуг на российском рынке, и не собирается их предоставлять**

Comment: Кстати ru.SO использует доменное имя, связанное с РФ. Так что "нет" в п.1 - это ложь

Comment: @DmitriySimushev `.ru` - связано - это country domain. `ru.` - нет, это указание на русский язык.

Comment: Какой-нибудь районный судья с вами не согласится. В разъяснении сказано "_доменное имя_". TLD или нет -- это детали. По-моему нужна более четкая юр. формулировка.

Comment: Более того, реклама ru.SO существует (баннер на главной странице в правой колонке). Вопрос когда именно баннерная сеть выдаст этот баннер где-то еще кроме SE -- вопрос времени.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вот поэтому [в комментах, которые тут уже подчистили], топикастера и отправили узнавать применимость закона в соответствующую организацию по месту жительства.